# How to override "postSaveHook" on users in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I want to override `postSaveHook` in `VirtueMart` so that when I edit any user then I can update some fields automatically.

```
protected function postSaveHook(JModelLegacy $model, $validData = array())
{
        //Add some code here..
        return;
}
```

This hook can be found in

> "administrator/components/com_users/controllers/user.php"

Comment: And what is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to override this hook and add some code that would change few values (like contact number) after saving the user.